# My command window crashes after i input a name. C

Tags: c

So that's my code, but every time I run it the command window crashes right after I input a name. I'm using Visual Basic, so it gives me a warning when I try to use:

```
scanf()
```

so instead i decided to use:

```
scanf_s
```

I also tried to change the `%s` in `scanf_s("%s\n", name)` to `%c`. It stopped crashing and executed the program but when it prints the name, it would just be a bunch of broken text.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   char name[30];

    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    scanf_s("%s\n", &name);
    printf("%s\n", name);
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s("%s\n", &name);` --> `scanf_s("%s",  name, sizeof(name));`

Answer (score 1):

Change the scanf line to

```
scanf("%29s", name);
```

Since your array has 30 positions, it shouldn't read more than 29. The last one is for the null terminating char